# Не появляются файлы в заданной папке функции move_uploaded_file(), в phpMyAdmin, именем файла становится первая буква реального имени

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysqli

```
<?php
session_start();
//Нужно добавить проверку введенного пароля админа!(Для себя)
    $connect=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','interbud');
    if ($connect){header('Location:../admin/admin-product-add.php');}
    elseif (!$connect){
        die("Error with connecting DataBase");
    }
    if (isset($_FILES["ProductPhoto"]) && $_FILES["ProductPhoto"]["tmp_name"] !=""){
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["ProductPhoto"]["tmp_name"] , "../img-products" . $_FILES["ProductPhoto"]["name"]);
        $file_name =$_FILES["ProductPhoto"]["name"];
    } else {
        $file_name="nophoto.jpg";
    }

    $productTitle = $_POST['ProductName'];
    $productPrice = $_POST['ProductPrice'];
    $productColor = $_POST['ProductColor'];
    $productQuantity = $_POST['ProductQuantity'];
    $productImage=$file_name['ProductPhoto'];
    mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `title`, `price`, `color`,`quantity`,`img`) VALUES (NULL,'$productTitle', '$productPrice', '$productColor', '$productQuantity', '$productImage')");
```

Comment: отключи подавление ошибок, потому что `$file_name` - строка, а тут `$productImage=$file_name['ProductPhoto'];` обращение к массиву с несуществующим ключом, от этого и *именем файла становится первая буква реального имени*

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.